# JSON Parser using POCO C++ Leaking in XCode instruments

Tags: c++, xcode, json, memory-leaks, poco-libraries

when I profile the following code using XCode instruments i get leaks (2.50KB)
The code is written from the examples using POCO C++ found here on SO. Are the leaks real or do they get reported since POCO C++ use it's own reference counting?
Have i inferred flaws in my code?

```
void RefComplexType::deserialize(Object::Ptr object){
if(object->has(NO) && !object->isNull(NO)){
    std::string str;
    Var no = object->get(NO);
    Object::Ptr subObject = no.extract<Object::Ptr>();
    if (subObject->has("$")&& !subObject->isNull("$")) {
        str = subObject->get("$").convert<std::string>();
    }else{
        str = no.convert<std::string>();
    }
    this->no = str;
}
if(object->has(NAME) && !object->isNull(NAME)){
    std::string str;
    Var name = object->get(NAME);
    Object::Ptr subObject = name.extract<Object::Ptr>();
    if (subObject->has("$")&& !subObject->isNull("$")) {
        str = subObject->get("$").convert<std::string>();
    }else{
        str = name.convert<std::string>();
    }

    this->name = str;
}
if(object->has(URL) && !object->isNull(URL)){
    std::string str;
    Var url = object->get(URL);
    Object::Ptr subObject = url.extract<Object::Ptr>();
    if (subObject->has("$")&& !object->isNull("$")) {
        str = subObject->get("$").convert<std::string>();
    }else{
        str = url.convert<std::string>();
    }
    this->url = str;
}
if(object->has(LOCATION) && !object->isNull(LOCATION)){
    Var locationRaw = object->get(LOCATION);
    Object::Ptr locationObject = locationRaw.extract<Object::Ptr>();
    this->location = new LocationComplexType(locationObject);
}
else {
    printf("NO! Location");

}

}
```

This is what instruments tell me (one red bar is shown after ~10 seconds of running) below is a part of the call tree:

```
Bytes Used  # Leaks     Symbol Name
928 Bytes   20.3%   26                std::string Poco::Dynamic::Var::convert<std::string>() const
768 Bytes   16.8%   16                 Poco::Dynamic::VarHolderImpl<Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::JSON::Object, Poco::ReferenceCounter, Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::JSON::Object> > >::convert(std::string&) const
160 Bytes    3.5%   10                 Poco::Dynamic::VarHolderImpl<int>::convert(std::string&) const
768 Bytes   16.8%   24              Poco::JSON::Parser::parse(std::istream&)
768 Bytes   16.8%   24               Poco::JSON::Parser::readObject()
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                Poco::JSON::Parser::readRow(bool)
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                 Poco::JSON::Parser::readValue(Poco::Token const*)
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                  Poco::JSON::Parser::readObject()
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                   Poco::JSON::Parser::readRow(bool)
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                    Poco::JSON::Parser::readValue(Poco::Token const*)
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                     Poco::JSON::Parser::readArray()
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                      Poco::JSON::Parser::readElements(bool)
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                       Poco::JSON::Parser::readValue(Poco::Token const*)
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                        Poco::JSON::Parser::readObject()
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                         Poco::JSON::Parser::readRow(bool)
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                          Poco::JSON::Parser::readValue(Poco::Token const*)
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                           Poco::JSON::Parser::readObject()
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                            Poco::JSON::Parser::readRow(bool)
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                             Poco::JSON::Parser::nextToken()
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                              Poco::StreamTokenizer::next()
768 Bytes   16.8%   24                               Poco::JSON::StringToken::finish(std::istream&)
544 Bytes   11.9%   17              std::list<RefComplexType, std::allocator<RefComplexType> >::_M_create_node(RefComplexType const&)
```

Comment: First question: What is the type of this->location (if it is not smart pointer this code will leak) ? Second question: are you setting the memory usage checkpoints between two points where you know for a fact there should be no difference in memory usage?

Comment: Could you please contemplate on how to use a smart pointer from Poco?

Comment: You are already using it with Object::Ptr entities. Declare RefComplexType::location as Poco::SharedPtr and then you can assign new-ed pointer to it without having to explicitly delete it.

Comment: I see, and could I also avoid the leak by setting

 delete this->location;
and this->location =0;

In the destructor?

Comment: Yes; setting it to zero is unnecessary because after RefComplexType object destruction, RefComplexType::location does not exist any more.